# Insert mysql состовной запрос

Tags: mysql, insert

Доброго!

Есть табличка примерно такая(client)

```
id | id_user | name | comment
```

И есть такая табличка(calls)

```
id | user_id | client_id | comment
```

как сделать добавление строк в таблицу calls по всем клиентам у кого id_user = 0

Comment: `insert into calls(колонки) select ... from client where id_user=0` (обратите внимание, часть select не обязана выбирать только колонки таблицы, это могут быть константы или любые другие, вычисляемые величины)